# MySQL replication - create two slaves but later make one of them master

Tags: mysql

We're migrating the DB to new DataCenter. As a result we need to create a new master and salve on the new DC.

I have the dump from Old Datacenter master DB (still in production use). I need to use this dump to create two databases. Both will be slaves but one of them will become master and then the other slave needs to replicate from new master.

```
DB_old_dc     - Master DB
DB_new_dc_001 - Slave replicating from DB_old_dc - Later this will become master.
DB_new_dc_002 - Salve replicating from DB_old_dc but later needs to replicate from DB_new_dc_001.
```

Can I just change the master IP on `DB_new_dc_002` to point to `DB_new_dc_001` and will it start working?

Or Do I have to wait till `DB_new_dc_001`  becomes master, then take a backup and create `DB_new_dc_002`   slave?

Comment: One thing to make sure of is that all replication has completed.  At that point, the data should be identical and it should be safe to rearrange the topology.  Also, consider using Galera.

Answer (score 1):

Your scheme really lacks comprehensiveness, so I'll just describe the way it has to be.

Say you have two DBs in DC A (master and slave, say they are named M and N) and you need to switch to DC B (master and slave too, Mng and Nng, where *ng* stands for *new-gen*).
Then you just set up Mng to be slave for M, and Nng to be slave for Mng (and don't forget to say `log_slave_updates` on Mng, just in case). Optionally  you also set `read_only` on on both Mng and Nng, just in case noone comes with master account and corrupts your new replica set.

When the moment comes, you do the following:

- stop the processing on DC A, say you put custom error pages "Sorry, we are migrating between DCs right now".
- stop M so no new data comes in it.
- `stop slave;` on Mng
- `set global read_only=off;` on Mng
- `reset slave all;` on Mng
- change connection descriptor in whatever is using DB master.
- remove the custom error page dummies, and voila, you're back online.

yeah, Nng just keeps on replicating.

Comment: Nng is now a salve of M. The reason for not doing it like `Nng a slave of Mng` is because the import on Mng takes a lot of time and I needed to save time so imported dump into Mng and Nng at the same time. Can I make it work just the way I mentioned?  I can ensure the DB's are stopped and synced before making Nng a slave of Mng after M goes down

Comment: Nnnnnnnnnnnope.

Comment: Okay I guess I'll take a new mysql dump from Mng and replicate it onto to Nng